# Get previous value of dropdown after onchange event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

How do I get the previous value of my AUTO-Generated dropdown menu after an onchange event? Example

```
<select class="form-control" name="Diabetes_UK_3147" id="Diabetes_UK_3147" onchange="return verifyUpdateResponseGross(this);">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="Possibly">Possibly</option>
  <option value="">N/A</option>
</select>
```

and I have this function

```
function verifyUpdateResponseGross(val)
{
  var updated_response = val.value;
  var colheader = val.name
  var before_gross = $('#new_gross').val(); 

  $.ajax({
  url: "qa/api/crm/getquestion", 
  type: 'GET',
  data: {'colheader':colheader},
  success: function(result){
    // var costperlead = result;
    // if(updated_response != "")
    // {
    //  var new_gross_amount = parseFloat(before_gross) + parseFloat(costperlead);
    //  $('#new_gross').val(new_gross_amount);
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //  var new_gross_amount = parseFloat(before_gross) - parseFloat(costperlead);
    //  $('#new_gross').val(new_gross_amount);
    // }
    // console.log(costperlead);
   }});
}
```

The reason I want to get the previous value is I need a checking that if the dropdown value is empty (N/A) then I need to perform some operation and if the value is not empty then I need perform another operation, But when the value gis not empty but the same from the previous value, then do nothing.

Those operation are those in comments. Thanks

**UPDATE** The id and name is autogenerated. That's why I have a

```
onchange="return verifyUpdateResponseGross(this);"
```

This will handle the change and do necessary operation.

This is it is autogenerated

[image]

Comment: How you are generating the menu? And which value got selected when page loads?

Comment: Store the previous value in a var and update it on every change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do it by jquery :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var previous;
         $("#Diabetes_UK_3147").on("focus click",function () {
            previous = this.value; // Old vaue 

        }).change(function() {
        var value =  this.value; // New Value
          $('span').text('Old Value : '+previous+' New Value : '+value)
        });

    })
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Laa2hL3b/

Edited : in auto-Generated dropdown you can add a custom class for example "myselectbox"

```
<select class="form-control  myselectbox"
```

and make change here

```
  $(".myselectbox").on(/* other code remain same */
```

Comment: Good answer but it only works a second time if blur is triggered on change, which it's not by the user

Comment: Why `select[id=Diabetes_UK_3147]` not `#Diabetes_UK_3147`?

Comment: This will work, but why the focus event? You can just put the code to store the previous value in the 'change' event handler, and also store it when the select is first created.

Comment: @MattBrowne OP used the term "auto-generated". No-one is sure whether that's on page load or afterwards, so it may not exist on page load. Both answers went for the safest bet.

Comment: @MattBrowne the `change` event is triggered after the value has changed, so you have no access to the old value.

Comment: @MattBrowne user want old value  "after an onchange event" as mentioned in question that's why i put focus to get old value

Comment: @ShailendraSharma This is possible but I can't use this, My drodpwns in Auto-Generated and their id is autogenerated too.  So I can't just hardcode it in a document ready function.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca you can use this. You didn't mention the IDs were autogenerated but you can adapt this answer.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca if your pattern is like Diabetes_UK_ RANDOM ? than we have solution

Comment: @Popnoodles I'll check and work around it. My dropdown is Auto generated as soon as page loads.

Comment: you can use $("select[id=^Diabetes_]") to match id start with Diabetes_ might be help yours

Comment: @ShailendraSharma The ID does't have a pattern. It came from database.

Comment: You can guys check my update, I posted how it is autogenerated.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca  i have edited my answer for over come auto generation problem

Comment: @ShailendraSharma I get it now. Just revised my code with your implementation Thank you.

Comment: @ojovirtual, as I mentioned, you can first store the previous value when the select element is first created (whether on page load or sometime after that). So the focus event is not needed, but we would need to see more of the OP's code to show how to do it without the focus event...anyway, using the focus event will work just fine, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use `data` to store the data instead a global variable:

```
$("#Diabetes_UK_3147").on("focus",function(){  
     $(this).data('previous',$(this).val());
}
```

Then you can access previous value by `$("#Diabetes_UK_3147").data('previous');`

[jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-*` as below. Also, remove the inline event handler `onchange="return verifyUpdateResponseGross(this);"` and do it the unobtrusive way.

```
var $select = $("#Diabetes_UK_3147");
$select.data("previous-val", $select.val());

$select.on("change", function() {

    var current_value = $(this).val();

    if (current_value == "") {
        //Do stuff when empty   
    } else if ( current_value != $(this).data("previousVal") && current_value != "" ) {
        //Do stuff when not empty and current value != previous value
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $select = $("#my-select");

$select.data("prevVal", $select.val()).data("currVal", $select.val()).on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("prevVal", $this.data("currVal")).data("currVal", $this.val());

    // do your staff here. Previous value is available in $this.data("prevVal")
});
```